# events fql return empty array

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to retrieve users events using the facebook php sdk, but i'm stuck, the api return an empty array

```
$user = $me['id'];
$fql = "SELECT eid, name, start_time, end_time 
    FROM event 
    WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid 
                  FROM event_member 
                  WHERE uid = 1552544515) 
    ORDER BY start_time LIMIT 5";
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
);
try {
$result = $facebook->api($params);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you have the `user_events` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)?

Comment: sure, the first thing i did when i created my facebook app, but thanks for the answer

Comment: So when you make a call to /me/permissions with the access token it confirms you've got that permission? and /me/events on the Graph API is also returning nothing?

Comment: I'm getting only these permissions calling /me/permissions 
installed and read_insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is returning nothing, the most likely reason is that your user hasn't granted the `user_events` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) during the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow.

Looking at your comments above, you may have added `user_events` to the permissions granted when a user goes through the Authenticated Referrals flow or via App Center, but regular users accessing the app directly need to go through one of the authentication flows from the document above, you're probably not doing this

Comment: Thanks, i'll look at my flow, probably that's the reason, and sorry my poor english.